# accessing params in actioncontroller hash but getting undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to access the params hash with `params["uppyResult"][0]["successful"][0]["id"]`, but this results in `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

My params are going through a POST request like this:

```
Parameters: 
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", 
  "item"=>{
   "title"=>"90", 
   "info"=>"90", 
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Next", 
  "uppyResult"=>"[
   { "successful":[
    {"id":"uppy-e6drjvpxoaikvhf/jpeg-1e-image/jpeg-153049-1626052105955","name":"E6DrJVPXoAIKVhf.jpeg"
    }
   ]}
  ]
 }
```

Testing up the params to see where I went wrong, `puts params["uppyResult"]` puts exactly what I would expect, whereas `puts params["uppyResult"][0]` puts just `[`. Everything after that is an undefined method. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content in `uppderResult` is a string and not array. That is why you get only `[`.

I believe the content is JSON encoded so you could just parse it to get an array.

```rb
JSON.parse(params["uppyResult"])[0]["successful"][0]["id"],
```

Please note that this code can still throw errors in production e.g. when malformed or nil. So you should implement make sure each element exist by e.g. using `dig`, `first`, parsing or `&` safe navigator.

A slightly more safe way to do it

```rb
def id
  successful_result[0].to_h['id']
end

def successful_result
  upper_result[0].to_h['successful'].to_a
end

def upper_result
  JSON.parse(params["uppyResult"])
rescue
  [] # rescue malformed JSON
end
```

Comment: that definitely was it! thank you for the answer and for the additional info. how would you suggest rescuing malformed json? sort of confused by what you mean

Comment: You expect JSON in your params but somebody could pass in `foobar` instead. Try to call `JSON.parse("foobar")` and you will see it will raise a `JSON::ParserError`. You should rescue it and return e.g. an empty array so your controller does not crash. See my second example.